# How to fix TypeError with respect to TensorFlow prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to perform neural network predictions with TensorFlow and the evaluation works fine but when I put the same data into prediction it gives a type error.

The data in training_data and test_data are both 2d numpy arrays of integers and training_labels and test_labels are 1d numpy arrays of integers.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Dense(24, activation=tf.nn.selu),
  keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
  keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.selu),
  keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])


model.compile(optimizer='SGD',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_data, training_labels, epochs=10)

test_loss,test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)

prediction = model.predict(test_data)
```

When taking out the prediction line the code works as expected but it now gives the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "learner.py", line 132, in <module>
    print("Prediction: " + model.predict(test_data))
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')
```

I've made sure that all the data is integers so I'm not sure why there's type conflict.

Comment: Can you try printing `test_data` and show us? `dtype('S32')` means it's a string I think.

Answer (score 0):

test_data should be the same datatype as type(training_data[0]) when using predict, and it will return a datatype of type(training_labels[0])

In addition,

```
print("Prediction: " + model.predict(test_data))
```

must be

```
print("Prediction: " + str(model.predict(test_data)))
```