# Keras PREDICTION throws 'TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4')'

Tags: python, keras, elmo

I built a slot filling (a type of sequence classification) model with structure: custom ELMo embeddings layer - BiLSTM - CRF.

It trains fine. But on prediction I get:

```
'TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4')'.
```

Note: U4 is an unsigned int.

In [a similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381334/how-to-fix-typeerror-with-respect-to-tensorflow-prediction), it was advised that "test_data should be the same datatype as type(training_data[0]) when using predict, and it will return a datatype of type(training_labels[0])". I've confirmed that yes, each of my test samples are the same type as training_data[0].

Full error message at the end of this post.

Note: the issue might be related to the fact that I previously needed to change my train and test data to np.strings, using:

```
X_train_sents = np.array(X_train_sents, dtype=np.str)
y_train_sents = np.array(y_train_sents, dtype=np.str)
```

This was to avoid an error during model building, namely: str has no attribute ndim. I get this error again if I don't convert the test data to np.str.

A colleague believes the problem is an add method (see error) somewhere deep in Keras. Apparently it's a special add method to work with unsigned ints, it shouldn't be causing issues like it is.

The custom layer is loosely based on [this person's repository](https://github.com/strongio/keras-elmo/blob/master/Elmo%20Keras.ipynb)

To reproduce the error: I've set up a github repository with the code and some dummy data [here](https://github.com/katherinemunro/SlotFilling_with_Keras_CustomELMo)

Full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-f71c3fcdc6d2> in <module>
     16 print(type(X_train_sents[0]))
     17 print(type(X_test_sents[0]))
---> 18 test_pred = model.predict(X_test_sents, y_test)

~/.conda/envs/base_munroke/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1167                                             batch_size=batch_size,
   1168                                             verbose=verbose,
-> 1169                                             steps=steps)
   1170 
   1171     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

~/.conda/envs/base_munroke/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in predict_loop(model, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps)
    280         # Sample-based predictions.
    281         outs = []
--> 282         batches = make_batches(num_samples, batch_size)
    283         index_array = np.arange(num_samples)
    284         for batch_index, (batch_start, batch_end) in enumerate(batches):

~/.conda/envs/base_munroke/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in make_batches(size, batch_size)
    367         A list of tuples of array indices.
    368     """
--> 369     num_batches = (size + batch_size - 1) // batch_size  # round up
    370     return [(i * batch_size, min(size, (i + 1) * batch_size))
    371             for i in range(num_batches)]

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, I found the solution: I was wrong to convert the y sets to np.str, e.g.

`y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype=np.str)`

I DO need to convert the y sets to arrays, but adding `dtype=np.str` to that line was just an oversight.

I hope my hours of pain bring some use to others! :)